# How to change sql date format in java

Tags: java, swing, sqlite, jdbc, jcalendar

I am using JDBC connectivity & Java Swing UI and there I used SqLite DB.

Here I have a java component that is jCalender to pickup date & i pick the date into String.

Firstly I convert string into java.util date then i convert java.util.date to java.sql.date but my date string format is "dd/MM/YYYY" &

Then
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY", Locale.ENGLISH);

and I set specific date format which written above. but there still problem when I search record between date.

Here I attached a copy of code plz guyz help me it is very important.

```
    String from_date = ((JTextField) txt_bilty_date_start.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
    String to_date = ((JTextField) txt_bilty_date_end.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();

    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date date1 = format.parse(from_date);
    Date date2= format.parse(to_date);

    java.sql.Date sqlDate1 = new java.sql.Date(date1.getTime());
    java.sql.Date sqlDate2 = new java.sql.Date(date2.getTime());

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");

    System.out.println("\t\tafter change date");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(sqlDate1));
    System.out.println(sdf.format(sqlDate2));

    String sql = "select * from employee where record_date BETWEEN '"+sdf.format(sqlDate1)+"' AND '"+sdf.format(sqlDate2)+"' ";

    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    tbl_employee.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

Comment: `"but there still problem when I search record between date."` -- you'll want to elaborate on this.

Comment: In case my comment above wasn't fully clear, it means that you'll want to go into much more detail describing just what problems you might be seeing, including posting any and all error or exception messages, and/or describing in decent detail any and all misbehaviors you might be encountering.

Comment: Essentially, you don't care, `java.util/sql.Date` is just a container class for the number of milliseconds since the unix epoch, it has no "format". Simply use a `PreparedStatement` and bind the `Date` object to the query directly and let the driver take care of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your record_date **is a SQL date** in your database (and not some varchar), try it like this with a proper [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

```
String sql = "select * from employee where record_date BETWEEN ? AND ?";
pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
pst.setDate(1, sqlDate1);
pst.setDate(2, sqlDate2);
rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

Note that the whole try / catch / check for closed in finally has become much more easier with [try-with-resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) introduced in Java 7.

If your date **is a varchar** you will need to **reverse the order of your fields** to have the most significant field up front - `yyyy MM dd` in some fashion. Only then will the results of a `String`/`VARCHAR` compare work like they should on string representations of strings.